# Is there any python (numpy) synonym to i-variables (e.g., irow, iradius, itheta, etc.) in DM scripting?

Tags: python, numpy, dm-script

I work with electron microscopy image processing mostly with digital microscopy (DM) scripting, and recently start to learn Python because of its wider versatility, rich open libraries, and cross-platform ability.

Does anybody know if there are any similar tools in Python (numpy) to index 2D (image), or 3D (spectrum image) arrays similar to DM's i-variables?

The i-variables are briefly introduced on page 11 of this tutorial about DM-scripting:
http://portal.tugraz.at/portal/page/portal/Files/felmi/images/DM-Script/DM-basic-scripting_bs.pdf

They are easy way to index any image-like 2D or 3D object, which is very convenient for image processing, e.g., generate mask functions

For example, the following DM-script

```
image t1 := RealImage ("test1", 4, 5, 5)
image t2 := RealImage ("test2", 4, 5, 5)
image t3 := RealImage ("test3", 4, 5, 5)
t1 = irow   
// the value in each pixel equals to the row index
t2 = iradius  
// the value in each pixel equals to the radius 
// (i.e., distance to the center pixel)
t3 = itheta  
// the value in each pixel quals to the angle (radian)
// to the center pixel (i.e., angle in polar representation) 
t1.showimage(); t2.showimage(); t3.showimage()
```

result in the following images (expressed here in spreadsheet, or say matrix form):

```
t1 = 
0   0   0   0   0
1   1   1   1   1
2   2   2   2   2
3   3   3   3   3
4   4   4   4   4

t2=
3.5355339   2.9154758   2.5495098   2.5495098   2.9154758
2.9154758   2.1213202   1.5811388   1.5811388   2.1213202
2.5495098   1.5811388   0.70710677  0.70710677  1.5811388
2.5495098   1.5811388   0.70710677  0.70710677  1.5811388
2.9154758   2.1213202   1.5811388   1.5811388   2.1213202

t3=
-2.3561945  -2.1112158  -1.7681919  -1.3734008  -1.0303768
-2.6011732  -2.3561945  -1.8925469  -1.2490457  -0.78539819
-2.9441972  -2.8198421  -2.3561945  -0.78539819 -0.32175055
2.9441972   2.8198421   2.3561945   0.78539819  0.32175055
2.6011732   2.3561945   1.8925469   1.2490457   0.78539819
```

Comment: It might help if you briefly explain what those are and how you want to use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent way to do this in NumPy is to use the [`numpy.indices`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.indices.html#numpy.indices) function.

So to do the same in NumPy as you did in DM (remember coordinates are always (y,x) in numpy, and that irow, say, is index of y-coordinates):

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np

test1 = np.random.random((5,5))
irow, icol = np.indices(test1.shape)

# to use iradius and itheta we need to get icol, irow centered
irow_centered = irow - test1.shape[0] / 2.0
icol_centered = icol - test1.shape[1] / 2.0

iradius = (icol_centered**2 + irow_centered**2)**0.5
itheta = np.arctan2(irow_centered, icol_centered)
```

Then

```
>>> irow
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
       [4, 4, 4, 4, 4]])
>>> iradius
array([[ 3.53553391,  2.91547595,  2.54950976,  2.54950976,  2.91547595],
       [ 2.91547595,  2.12132034,  1.58113883,  1.58113883,  2.12132034],
       [ 2.54950976,  1.58113883,  0.70710678,  0.70710678,  1.58113883],
       [ 2.54950976,  1.58113883,  0.70710678,  0.70710678,  1.58113883],
       [ 2.91547595,  2.12132034,  1.58113883,  1.58113883,  2.12132034]])
>>> itheta
array([[-2.35619449, -2.11121583, -1.76819189, -1.37340077, -1.03037683],
       [-2.60117315, -2.35619449, -1.89254688, -1.24904577, -0.78539816],
       [-2.94419709, -2.8198421 , -2.35619449, -0.78539816, -0.32175055],
       [ 2.94419709,  2.8198421 ,  2.35619449,  0.78539816,  0.32175055],
       [ 2.60117315,  2.35619449,  1.89254688,  1.24904577,  0.78539816]])
```

It's also possible to do this using the [`mgrid`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mgrid.html) and [`ogrid`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ogrid.html) functions. `mgrid` will return the coordinates in a fully populated array (the same shape as the source image, identical to numpy.indices) while `ogrid` returns row and column vectors of the right shape that often get automatically broadcast correctly.

If you're using this to create masks for Fourier-transformed images there's also the [np.fft.fftfreq](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fftfreq.html) function which will give you the frequencies of the pixels in the Fourier transform. I use the following to get the frequency squared at each pixel for a given image shape:

```
def get_freq_squared(shape, packed_complex=True):
    """Return the frequency squared for an n-d array.
    The returned image will match shape, if packed_complex is true the last
    dimension will be treated as 0,f,...,nf rather than 0,f,..., nf,...,-f
    """
    vecs = [np.fft.fftfreq(s, 1.0 / s) ** 2 for s in shape]

    if packed_complex:
        s = shape[-1]
        olds = (s-1)*2
        vecs[-1] = rfftfreq(olds, 1.0/olds)**2
    return reduce(np.add.outer, vecs)
```

Comment: Out of interest: How do speeds compare between modifying 3D data using DM script and *icol,irow,iplane* expressions and doing the equivalent things with the suggested Python methods? (Typical SI sizes of say 256x256x1024 assumed.)

Comment: I've jut discovered `numpy.indices(shape)` which is effectively the same as `np.mgrid[0:shape[0], 0:shape[1]]` so will update answer to use that

Answer (score 0):

[Pillow](https://python-pillow.github.io/) uses numpy arrays IIRC. Scipy has some image capabilities, but is bad at loading and saving images.